# Change the default folder permissions ubuntu

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, ubuntu-11.10

I am new to Linux, What bothers me is when i'm on my ruby on rails project and when i generate a controller or any file. If i looking into the file browser, it has a lock symbol. so, i have to do `chmod 757 -R file` everytime. So, is there anyway to set the default read and write permissions for my root folder?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can add your user to that secondary group. That way, your user has permission to edit those files.

Comment: You can also change ownership using `chown user:user -R <dirName>` to change default ownership and permissions to that user.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `umask` command. It can be applied inside the shell setup (so somewhere inside your ~/.bash_ or ~/.profile files). You specify a file permission mask with that command.

Alternatively it is a common pattern to use group ownership of files to allow two parties to access files vice versa, in this case a user person and a web server account maybe. This reduces the required rights to group level which is obviously more secore.